# Access SQL: Pull Related Information From Another Table Alongside Group By

Tags: sql, ms-access

This question involves the following code:

```
SELECT A.`FSR Name` AS [Last Name], 
    Min(A.`ACTUAL TEP IN`) AS [Date In], 
    Max(B.Site) AS Site, 
    Max(B.Position) AS Position,
    Max(B.Comments) AS Comments
FROM Deployments A
INNER JOIN Deployments AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.`Actual TEP In` > Now()
GROUP BY A.`FSR Name`;
```

The point of this code is to query for the very first date beyond today for each person, and only pull that one record. For example there can be many Smiths with dates before and after today, and I only want to show the record with Smith that is after today. The idea is to show each person's next date on a cascading list. For at least that part, this code works.

The problem I am having is the information that needs to come alongside it. The Group By forces aggregates so I keep pulling the wrong Site/Position/Comments fields when I do Min or Max to them. I'm really not sure what I should be doing at this point as it seems I'm a bit over my head. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note: I'm doing this in Access 2013.

Edit: Adding Rough Table

```
FSR Name    Date In     Site    Position    Comments
Bob         7/3/2014    A   OP          Notes
Joe         10/11/2013  B   OP  
Joe         8/4/2014    C   OP          Sea
Joe         9/1/2014    D   OP          Dep
Buckley     11/1/2012   A   OP          Transfer
Buckley     10/7/2012   B   OP  
Jones       6/10/2012   A   OP  
Jones       4/27/2013   A   OP          3 Notes
Jones       6/21/2011   B   OP  
Jones       3/26/2012   B   OP          5 Notes
Jones       6/10/2012   C   OP          1 Notes
Jones       3/23/2014   C   OP          2 Notes
Jones       7/5/2014    D   OP          dep
Calvillo    2/21/2014   A   OP  
Calvillo    10/3/2014   B   OP          COM
Calvillo    11/10/2014  A   OP          dep
Casey       5/2/2014    C   OP
```

Comment: When I run your query on the first 6 records, I get Bob - 7/3/2013 A OP Note and Joe - 8/4/2014 D OP Sea. Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT D1.[FSR Name], first(D2.[Date In]), ...
FROM Deployments AS D1 
     LEFT JOIN (select * from Deployments as D3 WHERE D3.[Date In] > Now() ORDER BY D3.[Date In]) as D2 
        ON D1.[FSR Name] = D2.[FSR Name]
group by D1.[FSR Name];
```

Solution Description: you are joining with the ordered list and `first()` will return values  from the same row. The `first()` aggregate function exists only in access, but other database engines have similar ones or you can deal even without it.

Comment: Please add an explanation how this solves the problem. Just dumping code isn't very helpful (and might lead to downvotes).

Comment: That works, thanks! Please note though that it requires a RIGHT join, not a LEFT join, in order to function properly. I can't explain why as I'm not that experienced with joins but it does seem to output the right information on a RIGHT join.